# Python 3.2: .txt to xml.txt

Tags: python, xml

Long time lurker, first time poster. 
I looked for a few solutions and have not found something that meets my needs exactly.

My assignment is as follows: example input file

student.txt

Contents:

```
    John Smith 
    Harvard
    4.00
    1600
```

"Your job is to write a python program, called dataCode(fileName), that takes, as an argument, the name of the file. It will open the file and create a new file with the data tagged. The output for the example file above would be the following:"

```
   <applicant>
   <name> John Smith </name>
   <school> Harvard </school>
   <gpa> 4.00 </gpa>
   <sat> 1600 </sat>
   </applicant>
```

Also: The name of the output file is similar to the name of the file being opened. If the input is student.txt, the out will be studentXML.txt

I was trying my hand with slicing (Borrowed this from another poster):

```
 tags = ['name', 'university', 'gpa', 'sat']  #Add desired 
 tags xml = ''#Add xml parsing  with open("data.txt") as data:


#read data and filter out whitespace
lines = [line.strip() for line in data.readlines()]

#Generating xml tags via slicing
xml = '\n'.join(['<{0:s}> {1:s} </{0:s)>'.format(tag, value)
                 for tag, value in zip(tags, lines)])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I apologize for not being more capable with the editor.

Trace back, using "data.txt" as file. (Is in same folder as project):

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Rokudo Hikaru\Dropbox\22c005\Python Project XML generation.py", line 7, in 
builtins.IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.txt'

After correcting the code

```
    with open(fileName) as data:

        #Read data and filter out whitespace
        lines = [line.strip() for line in data.readlines()]

        # Generating xml tags via slicing
        xml = '\n'.join(['<{0:s}> {1:s} </{0:s}>'.format(tag, value)
                         for tag, value in zip(tags, lines)])

    print xml
```

I am getting a call back on the print statement.

traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\foobar\XML generation.py", line 15, in 
Syntax Error:     print xml: c:\Users\foobar\XML generation.py, line 1513

Edit with "return xml" shoots it into the shell.
Some formatting issues, will tinker and see what happens.

Comment: So, how does your code fail? Provide the traceback please. There's a couple errors in there, but it's difficult to tell if they are in the code you're executing, or just formatting issues introduced by posting it with the StackOverflow editor.

Comment: This isn't the issue, but your `xml = '\n'.join()` call will fail because you have unbalanced brackets. you use `<{0}> {1} </{0)>` (the last curly brace is actually a paren)

Comment: What directory are you running the python script from? Relative paths are relative to your current working directory, not the location of the script.

Comment: Working directory, referring to the IDE directory, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple issues with your code, and as mentioned in the comments, it's hard to tell whether they are in the code you're actually executing, or just formatting issues introduced by posting it with the StackOverflow editor.

Either way, this is what's wrong with your code:

- You're using a relative path to `data.txt`. This path will be relative to your current working directory, *not* to the location of your Python script. So make sure you run the code from the same directory `data.txt` is in. *Or*, use an absolute path like `open("/home/foo/data.txt")`.
- The indentation is off. The first two lines are indented one space, they shouldn't be.
- That `tags` before the `xml` on the second line doesn't belong there and is a syntax error
- The with statement for opening the file is part of a comment:
  `with open("data.txt") as data:` should be on its own line, and the code below it indented by 4 spaces
- You're using a regular closing parentheses in `</{0:s)>` instead of a curly bracket

With that fixed, your code would look like this:

```
tags = ['name', 'university', 'gpa', 'sat']  #Add desired
xml = '' #Add xml parsing

with open("data.txt") as data:

    #read data and filter out whitespace
    lines = [line.strip() for line in data.readlines()]

    #Generating xml tags via slicing
    xml = '\n'.join(['<{0:s}> {1:s} </{0:s}>'.format(tag, value)
                     for tag, value in zip(tags, lines)])

print xml
```

Which yields

```
<name> John Smith </name>
<university> Harvard </university>
<gpa> 4.00 </gpa>
<sat> 1600 </sat>
```

So it almost works, you only need to enclose the xml with the opening and closing `applicant` tags.

**Edit:**
The working directory is where a program (any program, not just python) is started from when you use a shell. If you use an IDE, that totally depends on how that IDE handles / manipulates the working directory, you'd need to consult your IDE's docs for that.

You can print the working directory from Python by doing

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

that should help you determine where your working directory is, or your IDE sets it to be.

For passing in the filename as a command line argument, use

```
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1]
```

and call the script like `python generate.py data.txt`, from the directory where `data.txt` actually is.

However your assignment says:

> Your job is to write a python program, called `dataCode(fileName)`

A python program would usually be considered be a `.py` script, but `dataCode(fileName)` is a function signature. So you're probably just supposed to wrap your code in a function like this:

```
def dataCode(fileName):
    # ...
    with open(fileName) as data
        # ...
```

Comment: Absolute path will always work, whether it is in the same file or not? This is good and thank you very much. I'm pretty new to the language, so I get confused with the syntax from time to time. I appreciate the input on the code.